# Invalid List index 1004 error

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have a page which allows the users to check the fields they want to update and hit save. I have the below code on a page where multiple updates can be done by checking the checkbox.

```
<cfif isDefined("form.update")> 
    <cfset list1=#form.vselection#>

    <cfif isDefined("form.vselection") and listlen(form.vSelection) gt 0>
        <cfset vempID = #UCase(Right(cgi.remote_user,6))#> 
        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#listlen(form.vselection)#">
        <cfset vSelectedval = Listgetat(form.vselection,i)>
        <cfset v_position_id = Listgetat(form.vpostn,vselectedval)>
        <cfset v_sched_grp = Listgetat(form.vschgrp,vSelectedval)>
        <cfset v_accr_prof = Listgetat(form.vaccprof,vSelectedval)>
        <cfset v_pay_rule = Listgetat(form.vpayrul,vSelectedval)>       
        <cfset v_rest_days = Listgetat(form.vrestdays,vSelectedval)>                

        <!--- This is the update query --->
        <cfquery name="updpostn" datasource="mbtran">
            UPDATE KRONOS_IF.POSITION_DETAIL
            SET schedule_group  = '#v_sched_grp#',
                accrual_profile = '#v_accr_prof#',
                pay_rule_name = '#v_pay_rule#',
                rest_days = '#v_rest_days#'
            WHERE position_id = '#v_position_id#'
        </cfquery>               
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I am getting the Invalid list index 1004 error. I am not able to get around this. Please suggest as to what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Does your list contain empty elements?  ColdFusion ignores empty list elements; thus, the list "a,b,c,,,d" has four elements. Are you sure that all of those form fields have the same number of elements?  Which line is the error pointing to?  Check that form field.

Comment: what is the values of your vselection?

Comment: @Miguel-F: good thought! you can turn it on not to ignore the emptyvalues in listgetat() - see documentation http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#listgetat

Comment: Some suggestions: use structKeyExists(form, "update") instead of IsDefined.  You don't usually need to wrap variables in # # within a cfset, e.g. `<cfset list1=form.vselection>` is fine.  You set list1 = form.vselection, then you check that form.vselection is defined; if it wasn't defined the preceding line would error. And most importantly, use cfqueryparam in your query!

Comment: thanks! @ duncan: I am using oracle, can i still add cfqueryparam in my update statement?

Comment: Do any of the checkboxes have commas in their values (example: `<input type="checkbox" name="vSelection" value="a,b">`)? The list functions will see this value as two separate items in the list and consequently won't be able to properly determine the number of items.

Comment: No, its still not working. The checkboxes are being called like this <input type="checkbox" name="vSelection" value="#currentrow#">. They do not have commas in the value. I added cfqueryparam in the update but still does not work.

Comment: Check two or more boxes and submit the form.  Then <cfdump> your form scope and you'll see the commas in the vSelection field.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but that is not a good form structure for handling multiple updates. It is too brittle. If any of the values contains commas (or empty values) the whole thing breaks. You could easily generate unique field names by using an ID (or a counter value) to each "set" of form fields.

Comment: You never answered my questions. I see a few things that could be wrong but I'm not sure what your intent is. Do all of the form fields have the same number of elements? You are getting the value of `form.vselection` by the list index but then using the extracted value to attempt retrieval (by index) from the other form fields. What are the values of `form.vselection`? Should you just be using the index `i` for each of your `ListGetAt()` functions? How do these form fields relate to one another?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I have fixed this problem by adding a #currentrow# to the elements. and then just updating the one which was selected. <cfset vSelectedval = Listgetat(form.vselection,i)>   
   <cfset v_position_id = "form.vpostn_" & vSelectedval>
   <cfset v_position_id = Evaluate(v_position_id)>   
   <cfset v_sched_grp = "form.vschgrp_" & vSelectedval>

Comment: @user747291- Yes, unique field names are better suited in this case. However, no need for `evaluate`. Use associative array notation: ie `FORM["fieldName"& counter]`

Answer (score 1):

If form.vselection is a bunch of checkboxes, empty list elements should not be be an issue.  However, let' look at these three lines.

```
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#listlen(form.vselection)#">
    <cfset vSelectedval = Listgetat(form.vselection,i)>
    <cfset v_position_id = Listgetat(form.vpostn,vselectedval)>
```

Let's also assume that the first element of form.vselection is 1004.  The next command is looking for the 1004th element of form.vpostn.  Chance are that form field is a list of 1 element, not 1004.

That's the problem.  Let us know if you need help solving it.

Comment: Yes please can you elaborate?

Comment: It's hard to elaborate without knowing what part you found unclear.  But I'll try.  If form.vpostn is a textbox or dropdown, or something similar, then it's value will be 'fred' or 2, or something like that.  If you treat those values as lists, their lengths will be 1.  Therefore when you try to get any element from that list where the position is greater than 1, you can't.  Hence your error.

Comment: I am debugging the code and the value of the v_position_id is showing for the checkbox i selected. Its position is showing as 1 that is vSelectedval. Should it be displaying the id of the checkbox?

Comment: It might be another form field that is causing the problem.  Or, it might be for a later value of the checkbox.  Or, you may have checked a different box.  If you know what box has a value of 1004, check just that box and troubleshoot with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend turning your list into an array to find the values. Much cleaner code than `listGetAt` in my opinion.

```
<cfset list1 = listtoarray(form.vselection,',',true)>//use true to include empty rows for blank list items

<cfif structKeyExists(form,'vselection') and NOT arrayIsEmpty(list1)>
    <cfset vempID = UCase(Right(cgi.remote_user,6))> 
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#listlen(form.vselection)#">
        <cfset vSelectedval = list1[i]>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```